# priority between set subtraction and set union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I write $ \Omega \setminus \Gamma \cup \Theta$ this means $ \Omega \setminus  \left( \Gamma \cup \Theta \right) $ or $ \left( \Omega \setminus \Gamma \right) \cup \Theta$?

Comment: Might a duplicate of this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266182/order-of-precedence-of-set-operators

Comment: It depends on your book notations.

Comment: The same as the question: $a - b + c$ means   $(a - b) + c$ or  $a - (b + c)$

Answer (score 4):

I would personally read it as $(\Omega\setminus\Gamma)\cup \Theta$, by analogy with how $-$ and and $+$ work in arithmetic expressions.

But the real truth is that there is not a strong universally-followed convention here. As a writer you would do your readers a favor by parenthesizing fully (or explicitly stating which convention you follow); as a reader you may need to consider both readings and figure out for yourself what makes the author's point make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way,

$$\Omega\cap\Gamma^c\cup\Theta$$

which doesn't give you a priority order, but allows you to use the same as for union and intersection.

Comment: Or (with the other choice) you could write it $\Omega \cap (\Gamma \cup \Theta)^c$.

Comment: In many set-theoretic contexts complementation doesn’t make sense.