# Are there precedence (BODMAS kind of) rules in set operations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

Let's say we have three set's $A, B, C$ with elements $\in \Bbb Z$ . If there is an operation

$A \setminus (A\cap (B \setminus C)^\mathsf{c})\cup(B\cap C)$

let $x=(A\cap (B\setminus C)^\mathsf{c})$ and $y=(B\cap C)$ , from the above operation

$\therefore A \setminus x\cup y$

Now my question is
what operation must we go for first $A\setminus x$ or $x\cup y$, as they might result in different answers?

As there is a [BODMAS](https://thirdspacelearning.com/blog/what-is-bodmas/#:%7E:text=Bodmas%20stands%20for%20Brackets%2C%20Orders,%2FMultiplication%2C%20Addition%2FSubtraction.) rule in Algebra, is there similar kind of rule in set's operations also?

**PS:** $X\setminus Y \Rightarrow X-Y$

The [Khan Academy video](https://youtu.be/OCNXS_m1HWU) where he does a question using this relation. Just for the sake of example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of precedence of set operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266182/order-of-precedence-of-set-operators)

Comment: In your "PS:" you have the slash going the other way from the rest of your question. Typo?

Comment: @Amit Rajaraman Thanks for the suggestion but the answers were only discussing how the two different operations are unequal, but not how can we do it.

Comment: @ coffeemath thanks

Comment: @user235005 The top answer there answers your question.

Comment: I feel that adding the (very usual) mathematical expression called "precedence of operations" would be a plus in your title : see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: One thing is certain : there is no precedence of $\cap$ over $\cup$, as it could have been, knowing the boolean correspondence of $\cap$ with multiplication and $\cup$ with addition.

Comment: @Amit Rajaraman Ook It says it is not right to write without brackets, we must rather use brackets for precise meaning, hence there is no such thing as "Order of precedence of set operators", just brackets need to be solved, right?, Also is it fair to conclude that, what is done in the video is not right?

Comment: @Jean Marie thanks for the edit

Comment: @Jean Marie thanks for ur interesting comment --"there is no precedence of ∩ over ∪, as it could have been, knowing the Boolean correspondence of ∩ with multiplication and ∪ with addition."

Answer (score 1):

Just as arithmetic features binary operations on numbers, set theory features binary operations on sets. The binary operations are Idempotent, Commutative, Associative, Distributive, etc.

In elementary set theory, the three binary operations: union, intersection, and difference are all equal in the order of precedence. The three binary operation (known as basic operations) have a higher precedence than other set operations such as symmetric difference or cartesian product.

From the example given in the question (or the [Khan Academy video](https://youtu.be/OCNXS_m1HWU)), $(A \setminus x)\cup y$ = $A \setminus (x\cup y)$. Let us verify this with the example;
$$A = \{3, 7, -5, 0, 13\}$$
$$B = \{0, 17, 3, 9, 19\}$$
$$C = \{18, 19, 3, 17\}$$

Let us consider $x=(A\cap (B\setminus C)^\mathsf{c}) =\{3, 7, -5, 13\}$ and $y=(B\cap C)=\{17, 3, 19\}$.
Clearly, $(A \setminus x)\cup y$ = $A \setminus (x\cup y)=\{0, 17, 3, 19\}$.

See Algebra of sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets

Comment: thanks for the answer it was very helpful, i must have been careful with my calculations.

Comment: Is it that we must always use brackets whenever working with the three operations (i.e. $\setminus , \cap , \cup$) for preciseness?